# Perl WWW::Mechanize foreach loop follow links and see if they give a 401 response

Tags: perl, mechanize, http-status-code-401

I have been trying to **create a program using perl www::Mechanize that will follow all of the links on a webpage and then check each one of them to see if any of them return a 401 response** (using mech->status and so on)

If anyone could show me a perl www::Mechanize program to do it that would be great.

I have tried a number of ways of doing it but cant seem to get it to work correctly.

I am fairly experienced with perl www::Mechanize and have done much more complex things with it but **just can't get it to follow each of the links in the foreach loop and see if they give a 401 response header.**

Your help is much appreciated, thanks CM

Comment: Could you show us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: On my iPad so can't show exact code but it basically went something like this

Comment: On my iPad so can't show exact code but it basically went something like this my @links = $mech->links; foreach (at-sign)links {($mech->follow_link) if $mech->status = 401; print "401 status found"; } . I've obviously missed parts out because I can't remember the whole lot off the top of my head but you get the idea. If you could show me some example code that would be extremely helpful because i could work out what key part I am missing from mine. Thank you in advance, cm

Comment: It's the checking of every link in the array for a 401 response that is not being done properly, I think.

Comment: You'd better post your code so we can see exactly what you've done

Comment: Okay then, will have to do that tomorrow though because don't have access to it now,  Thanks a lot, cm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach my $link ( $mech->find_all_links() ) {

    $mech->follow_link($link);
    if ( $mech->status() == 401 ) {

        say "401 status found";
    }
}
```

You need to use **==** instead of *=* to check if one number equals to another in Perl!

Comment: I thought so too when I saw the OP's (pseudo)code in the comment, but wanted to give him the benefit of the doubt until he posted the actual code he used